# B1/B2 visa to J-1 visa, back to B1/B2 visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, j1-visas, vacations

Back in 2011, I applied and got my B1/B2 visa, which is still valid until 2016, but then in 2013, I got an internship in NYC, and got the J-1 visa which was only valid for 6 months (length of my internship) plus the grace period, so I went for my internship, and came back right after it was over. 
Now I've been back in my country of residence for almost 2 years (it'll be exactly 2 years in Aug'15).

I guess I just wanted to know if anyone knows whether or not this could be a problem for me to enter the US again for a 3 week holiday next month (July'15) with my B1/B2 visa that I got in 2011?

I'm just afraid that when I got the J-1 visa, it automatically cancelled my B1/B2 visa even if people in the consulate didn't say anything about it. Maybe I'm just worrying for no reason, but some countries do that, they automatically cancel your previous visa when you get another one, even if the newer visa is for a different purpose (ie. tourist visa - business visa, etc).

So I just wanted to know that, because I've Googled it, and also looked at [US Travel Docs](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/) website FAQ, but no one has mentioned this problem so far.
Also I don't think we can contact or go to the US embassy to ask questions, as they are very strict about appointments and everything.

Please note, on my J-1, it states "two-year rule does not apply".
Also my B1/B2 is still perfectly fine physically, undamaged, unaltered in any way.
However I recently got a new passport, and my B1/B2 (still valid) and J-1 visa are all in my old one.

Answer (score 7):

They often cancel your existing US visas when you apply for a US visa, but not always. In other words, it is possible to have two valid US visas in your passport at the same time. For example, if you apply for a work visa but have plans to have a brief visit before you start work, then you can keep your visitor visa along with the work visa. Maybe your situation is similar, with the short J1 program.

In any case, if they cancelled it, you would know -- it will be written in big letters on the visa. From your description, they did not cancel your B1/B2 visa. The reason why they did not cancel it is not important. Your B1/B2 visa is still valid and you can use it.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your answer.
See the thing is I've never seen a cancelled US visa before in my life LOL.
And I don't know why the people in the embassy just didn't tell me anything when I picked up my visa.

Anyway, I've also asked around, and some people (I asked some travel agents, and my friends) said exactly the same as you, if they did cancel it, they would've written or stamped something on it, and I would know.

So thanks again, hopefully I won't be rejected at the port of entry lol

Comment: On a cancelled visa, they write in big letters something like "C.W.O.P" - "Cancelled without prejudice". This means that the visa has been cancelled, and the reason for that is something that does not affect future visa applications.

Comment: @traveller001 https://www.google.com/search?q=us+visa+cancelled&tbm=isch

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @traveller001 - but in my case the B1 visa has been cancelled without prejudice. Would it be possible to re-issue the B1 visa or do I have to go through the entire B1 application process again?